# .Net Reflector: the "Location" reference for a DLL

Tags: c#

Recently, our company performed a migration from one server to a brand new one. Both servers use Windows XP with IIS6.

After the migration including 9 web applications, 2 of the applications rendered errors upon visiting their pages, which included interacting with SQL Server reads.

I used .Net Reflector to view the class files contained within the DLLs. We were thinking there may have been a hard-coded reference in the code that was causing a problem, but I found nothing. I did notice however in the small window at the lower left of the .Net Reflector screen, there was the following info about the DLL in question (I have replaced the server name and application name with generic references):

```
// Assembly SalesReports, Version 1.0.0.0

Location: \\<old server name>\d$\WEBAPPS\<application name>\bin\SalesReports.dll 
Name: SalesReports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
Type: Library
```

In the snippet above where it says `<old server name>`, the DLL that I am currently viewing actually resides on a new server.  I expected the Location to reference the new server path.  This may be the source of our company's problem with the execution of the applications.  My problem is that I don't know where this `<old server name>` actually resides in reference to the physical DLL itself.

Is there a way to override the `<old server name>` reference with the new server name in a `web.config` file, or something similar?  Or is there a way to use ReflexIL to change the `<old server name>` to a new server path?  The method that was used for the migration was a Windows Explorer drag and drop copy.  Perhaps a different copy method would have updated the location referenced here. I'm just grasping at straws right now.

Thanks in advance for any help on this matter.

Comment: It just shows you the path that you navigated to when you used File + Open Assembly.  Apparently you picked `\\d$` for some reason, a share on another machine.  Which one is unguessable.  You don't sound close to identifying the problem, use Fuslogvw.exe

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Actually, currently I'm sitting on Server 2 (new server) in Windows Explorer, which contains the copied folders and files from Server 1 (old server).  Yet, the location reference, for the DLL that I right-clicked on, is referencing Server 1.  This is what's confusing.  Somehow that Server 1 reference path is being associated with the DLL file I opened on Server 2.